# security.xml to java config, how to implement a custom securityMetataSource

Tags: spring-security

So, in my migration towards a javaconfig style spring security, I'm running into an issue with regards to a custom securityMetadataSource. It doesn't seem to get picked up automatically, and I'm not sure how to include it in the http security wizard. Because we have multiple site configurations that can have various security configurations, we keep the security in a separate site specific config class

```
  @Bean
  DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource(){

    SecurityExpressionHandler<FilterInvocation> securityExpressionHandler = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();

    LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> map = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>>();
    processSecurityPath(map,"/signin/**","permitAll");
    processSecurityPath(map,"/redirect/**","permitAll");

    processSecurityPath(map,"/*/*/account/g_product/add*/**" ,"hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_EDITOR')");

    processSecurityPath(map,"/**" ,"permitAll");    

    ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource ms = new ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource(map, securityExpressionHandler);

    return ms;
}

private void processSecurityPath(LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, Collection<ConfigAttribute>> map, String path, String securityRule){
    map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher(path), Arrays.<ConfigAttribute>asList(new SecurityConfig(securityRule)));
}
```

And this is the main security config

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http
    .addFilter(myFilterSecurityInterceptor)
    .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new MyAccessDeniedHandler())
      .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    //                  .anyRequest().authenticated() // this should be handled by the DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource that is part of the project specific config
    [...]
```

Comment: You cannot use a custom SecurityMetadatSource because authorizeRequests provides a custom dsl that is specific to the implementation used. Instead, you would avoid using authorizeRequests in favor of creating a custom FilterSecurityInterceptor and adding that using http.addFilter (as it appears you have done). You may be overriding your configuration with the authorizeRequests. I'd be curious why you feel that you cannot use authorize requests.

Comment: Well, I may just not understand it correctly, but I have a central spring security config class. On the other hand, on the same code base I have multiple potential "application specific" config classes with different security requirements. For that reason I use the securityMetadataSource. I guess I just don't see how I can use authorizeRequests if the path specification is variable

Comment: You can inject the variables into the security configuration and then use those to create your mappings. Does that help? If not, please update your question to include what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you give an example of applying those variables? Both the number of paths and the paths themselves vary according to the configuration.

Am I correct in understanding that if I group the ant paths by access role, I can do it like this?

.antMatchers("path1","path2").hasRole("hasRole('ROLE_ENDUSER')")

It's a bit inconvenient this way, but I guess workable. I would prefer to just feed in my securityDataMetaSource and be done with it.

Also, I don't really see how I can make this generic, since I would have to loop over the settings of my securitymetadatasource?